# Как правильно создать Constraint аннотацию для валидации

Tags: java, java-ee, аннотации

Всем привет!

Знакомлюсь с аннотациями в Java EE. При тестировании простой программы не выводится в консоль то что должно быть вывединно при удачном тесте, в `EmailValidator` классе!

В чем можеть быть проблема ? Буду рад вариантам нового кода/исправленного кода!

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {EmailValidation.EmailValidator.class})
public @interface EmailValidation {

String regularExpression() default "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\\\+]+(\\\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@\"\n" +
        "\t\t+ \"[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
String message() default "Wrong input";


 class EmailValidator implements ConstraintValidator<EmailValidation,User>{

 private static String regEX;
 private static String message;
 private static String emailField;

 public void initialize(EmailValidation email) {

     regEX = email.regularExpression();
     message = email.message();
     emailField = User.getEmail();
 }

 public boolean isValid(User user, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
     return emailValidation(user);
 }

 private boolean emailValidation(User user){

        if(!(emailField.matches(regEX))){

            System.out.print("Checking");

            System.out.print(message);
            return false;

        }


     System.out.print("AllMatches");

     return true;
 }
}
```

=========================================================================

```
public class ApplTest {

public static void main(String [] string){

    User user = new User("Aleksey","13224","Aleksey.Alekseev88@gmail.com");

  }
}
```

=========================================================================

```
public class User {

public static String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public static String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public static String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public User(String userName, String password, String email) {

    setUserName(userName);
    setEmail(email);
    setPassword(password);
}

private static void setUserName(String userName) {
    User.userName = userName;
}

private static void setPassword(String password) {
    User.password = password;
}

private static void setEmail(String email) {
    User.email = email;
}

private static String userName;
private static String password;

@EmailValidation // Не работает!
private static String email;
```

}

Comment: **Выведено**, ну ради всего святого

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Аннотации не работают сами по себе. Нужно пропустить класс через обработчик, который понимает данный вид аннотаций. Для валидации используется `javax.validation.Validator`. Но это интерфейс, надо получить конкретную реализацию через фабрику, например:

```
ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = validatorFactory.getValidator();
```

Теперь можно использовать валидатор для валидации и получить список всех нарушений:

```
User user = new User(...);

Set<ConstraintViolation<User>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(user);
for (ConstraintViolation<User> cv : constraintViolations) {
    System.out.println(cv.getMessage());
}
```

И ещё. Какой смысл валидации статичного поля? (Даже не знаю работает ли она на них в принципе?)

П.С.
Для использования валидации в приложении java se необходимо подключить к прожекту одну из библиотек валидации. При подключении чётко следовать инструкциям поставщика библиотеки, чтобы не пропустить зависимости самой библиотеки. Вот например hibernate-validator. Кроме самого hibernate-validator надо добавить ещё три артефакта по инструкции http://hibernate.org/validator/documentation/getting-started/.

Ну и валидатор из вопроса надо ещё править, ибо он в таком виде в принципе не рабочий.
Этот рабочий, за исключением регулярного выражения, которое даже не пытался править:

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {EmailValidation.EmailValidator.class})
public @interface EmailValidation {
    String regularExpression() default "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\\\+]+(\\\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@\"\n" +
        "\t\t+ \"[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
    String message() default "Wrong input";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
    // Эти два Class-а вверху нужны для чего-то, без них не запускается

    //
    // class EmailValidator implements ConstraintValidator<EmailValidation,User>
    // Если аннотация планируется применяться к String, то при чём тут User?
    //          
    public static class EmailValidator implements ConstraintValidator<EmailValidation, String> {
        private String regEX;
        private String message;

        public EmailValidator() {
        }

        @Override
        public void initialize(EmailValidation a) {
            regEX = a.regularExpression();
            message = a.message();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isValid(String t, ConstraintValidatorContext cvc) {
            System.out.println("Checking...");
            if (t != null && !(t.matches(regEX))) {
                System.out.println(message);
                return false;
            }
            System.out.println("Valid input");
            return true;
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Люди спокойно тут не опытный человек, ошибки разрешены.
Спасибо за направление !

Comment: Спасибо попробую!

Comment: Не понятен смысл добавленых элементов в аннотацию. Что они меняют в моём случаи ?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/572683/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-nullpointer-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8

Comment: @Maks.Burkov Просто программа не запускалась, ругаясь на отсутствие этих элементов. Для чего они нужны можно почитать в литературке. Я не читал:)

Comment: Ещё обратите внимание, что класс `EmailValidator` у меня `вложенный статичный`, поэтому можно получить его экземпляр где угодно (он ещё и `public`). Ваш же не статичный, внутренний (для внутреннего использования внутри внешнего класса), как получить объект этого класса вне `EmailValidation`? Библиотека валидации не сможет его получить в принципе. Не сможет им ничего проверить. Потом в моём классе `<EmailValidation, String>` вместо `<EmailValidation, User>`. Вы же проверяете не класс User в целом, а строку адреса email.

Comment: Насчёт вложенности наврал. Когда класс внутри интерфейса (аннотации тоже вроде интерфейсы), то он неявным образом становится public static

Comment: Может знаете где я смогу найти информацию более подробную о том зачем надо добавлять для каждой такой Constraint аннотации   "" Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {}; ""  ??
Из информации API EE http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/Constraint.html не особо тшательно говорится про это!

Comment: Может здесь. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.2/reference/en-US/html/  Про группы точно глава есть. А так везде пишут что надо, требуется и всё.